# loop regression when column names have special characters

Tags: r, loops, linear-regression, lm, r-colnames

Dummy data shown below. I tried amending my loop regression code to account for spaces in the column names, but it still gives an error. Additionally, I'm not sure how to adjust `.x` to account for spaces in the independent variable column names too.
The purpose of the code is to regress the first column against each of the subsequent columns one at a time. i.e. `Canada Price ~ Global Price`, then `Canada Price ~ Canada Bond Price` and so on.

```
lm.test <- map_dfr(
  set_names(names(df)),
  ~ tidy(lm(as.formula(paste("`",colnames(df[1]),"`","~", .x)),
            data = df)),
  .id = "predictor")
```

| Canada Price | Global Price | Canada 2Y Bond Price | US - Canada Inflation | Oil Price |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| -0.030661468 | -0.000207995 | 0.084 | -0.075 | 0.002116 |
| -0.034269304 | -0.140212141 | 0.363 | -1.062 | -0.06122 |
| 0.02371464 | 0.019987 | -0.781 | 0.273 | 0.209895 |
| -0.007971484 | 0.090597341 | -0.221 | 0.068 | -0.10657 |
| 0.005342716 | 0.060627149 | 0.151 | 0.234 | -0.22191 |
| -0.002210376 | 0.046010712 | -0.106 | 0.13 | 0.073975 |
| 0.018338299 | 0.019799534 | 0.036 | 0.005 | 0.058091 |
| 0.000662471 | -0.025356047 | 0.523 | 0.045 | -0.03765 |
| 0.002124411 | 0.045979342 | -0.433 | 0.282 | 0.365933 |
| 0.034191555 | 0.043211347 | -0.08 | 0.147 | 0.113365 |
| -0.011470069 | -0.033773176 | 0.396 | -0.037 | -0.09753 |
| 0.007039847 | 0.050327089 | -0.052 | 0.151 | 0.145487 |
| -0.028872959 | -0.004501371 | 0.324 | -0.214 | 0.064282 |
| 0.009244373 | -0.00092413 | 0.166 | -0.066 | 0.076961 |
| 0.017448201 | -0.010638258 | -0.179 | 0.053 | 0.108548 |
| -0.002379819 | 0.050111674 | 0.352 | -0.161 | -0.11261 |
| -0.002103406 | 0.03094893 | 0.121 | 0.106 | 0.130575 |
| 0.019154969 | 0.08307375 | 0.051 | 0.149 | 0.041074 |
| -0.00124318 | -0.054526954 | 0.345 | 0.032 | 0.079687 |
| -0.001241636 | 0.003319001 | -0.289 | 0.219 | 0.100941 |

---

## Edit

Data in `dput` format.

```
df1 <-
  structure(list(
    `Canada Price` = c(-0.030661468, -0.034269304, 0.02371464, -0.007971484, 
                       0.005342716, -0.002210376, 0.018338299, 0.000662471, 0.002124411, 
                       0.034191555, -0.011470069, 0.007039847, -0.028872959, 0.009244373, 
                       0.017448201, -0.002379819, -0.002103406, 0.019154969, -0.00124318, -0.001241636), 
    `Global Price` = c(-0.000207995, -0.140212141, 0.019987, 0.090597341, 
                       0.060627149, 0.046010712, 0.019799534, -0.025356047, 0.045979342,
                       0.043211347, -0.033773176, 0.050327089, -0.004501371, -0.00092413, 
                       -0.010638258, 0.050111674, 0.03094893, 0.08307375, -0.054526954, 0.003319001), 
    `Canada 2Y Bond Price` = c(0.084, 0.363, -0.781, -0.221, 0.151, -0.106, 
                               0.036, 0.523, -0.433, -0.08, 0.396, -0.052, 0.324, 0.166, -0.179, 0.352,
                               0.121, 0.051, 0.345, -0.289), 
    `US - Canada Inflation` = c(-0.075, -1.062, 0.273, 0.068, 
                                0.234, 0.13, 0.005, 0.045, 0.282, 0.147, -0.037, 0.151, -0.214, 
                                -0.066, 0.053, -0.161, 0.106, 0.149, 0.032, 0.219), 
    `Oil Price` = c(0.002116, -0.06122, 0.209895, -0.10657, -0.22191, 0.073975, 
                    0.058091, -0.03765, 0.365933, 0.113365, -0.09753, 0.145487, 0.064282, 
                    0.076961, 0.108548, -0.11261, 0.130575, 0.041074, 0.079687, 0.100941)), 
    class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -20L))
```

Comment: 1. The best approach would appear to be renaming the columns. 2. I strongly advise that you reshape the data to long format and use `nlme::lmList`.

Comment: Please share data in a useful format. Usually we prefer the output of `dput(df)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a solution to run regressions on all other columns but the first.
The formula is created with `reformulate`.

```r
suppressPackageStartupMessages({
  library(magrittr)
  library(purrr)
})

# create the formula with 'value' as regressor,
# it will be the column name after pivoting to long format
fmla <- reformulate("value", response = names(df1)[1L] |> as.name())
# run the regressions
lm_fit_list <- df1 %>%
  tidyr::pivot_longer(-1L) %>%
  split(.$name) %>%
  map(\(df) lm(fmla, data = df))
  
# this gives some statistics
lm_smry_list <- lm_fit_list %>% map(summary)
lm_smry_list %>% map(coef)
#> $`Canada 2Y Bond Price`
#>                 Estimate  Std. Error    t value   Pr(>|t|)
#> (Intercept)  0.001736073 0.003667346  0.4733866 0.64162781
#> value       -0.025789455 0.011690588 -2.2060015 0.04061964
#> 
#> $`Global Price`
#>                 Estimate  Std. Error    t value   Pr(>|t|)
#> (Intercept) -0.001515084 0.003712875 -0.4080622 0.68804100
#> value        0.164831106 0.070018144  2.3541199 0.03012634
#> 
#> $`Oil Price`
#>                 Estimate  Std. Error    t value  Pr(>|t|)
#> (Intercept) -0.001424249 0.004112478 -0.3463238 0.7331147
#> value        0.046411939 0.030404220  1.5264966 0.1442663
#> 
#> $`US - Canada Inflation`
#>                 Estimate  Std. Error    t value    Pr(>|t|)
#> (Intercept) 0.0001923356 0.003176245 0.06055441 0.952381362
#> value       0.0393945114 0.011325922 3.47826091 0.002683133
```

<sup>Created on 2024-02-23 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

---

## Edit

After running `summary` on the output list, you can extract the values you want from this second list (of summaries).

```r
suppressPackageStartupMessages({
  library(magrittr)
  library(purrr)
})

# create the formula with 'value' as regressor,
# it will be the column name after pivoting to long format
fmla <- reformulate("value", response = names(df1)[1L] |> as.name())
# run the regressions
lm_fit_list <- df1 %>%
  tidyr::pivot_longer(-1L) %>%
  split(.$name) %>%
  map(\(df) lm(fmla, data = df))
  
lm_smry_list <- lm_fit_list %>% map(summary)

stats <- lm_smry_list %>%
  map(coef) %>%
  map2(names(lm_smry_list), \(x, y) {
    data.frame(Variable = y) %>% cbind(x)
  }) %>% 
  list_rbind() 
row.names(stats) <- NULL
stats
#>                Variable      Estimate  Std. Error     t value    Pr(>|t|)
#> 1  Canada 2Y Bond Price  0.0017360725 0.003667346  0.47338661 0.641627809
#> 2  Canada 2Y Bond Price -0.0257894550 0.011690588 -2.20600149 0.040619640
#> 3          Global Price -0.0015150839 0.003712875 -0.40806217 0.688041004
#> 4          Global Price  0.1648311056 0.070018144  2.35411990 0.030126342
#> 5             Oil Price -0.0014242490 0.004112478 -0.34632381 0.733114717
#> 6             Oil Price  0.0464119390 0.030404220  1.52649664 0.144266337
#> 7 US - Canada Inflation  0.0001923356 0.003176245  0.06055441 0.952381362
#> 8 US - Canada Inflation  0.0393945114 0.011325922  3.47826091 0.002683133
```

<sup>Created on 2024-02-23 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Thanks for this!
Another small question, how do I extract only the coefficient value and its std error, t value, etc. for each of the variables 
i.e.  first column - variable name; second column - coefficient value estimate; third column - coefficient std. error; etc.

Answer (score 1):

```
Map(\(x, y)coef(summary(lm(y~x))), df1[-1], df1[1])

$`Canada 2Y Bond Price`
                           Estimate  Std. Error    t value   Pr(>|t|)
(Intercept)             0.001736073 0.003667346  0.4733866 0.64162781
`Canada 2Y Bond Price` -0.025789455 0.011690588 -2.2060015 0.04061964

$`Global Price`
                   Estimate  Std. Error    t value   Pr(>|t|)
(Intercept)    -0.001515084 0.003712875 -0.4080622 0.68804100
`Global Price`  0.164831106 0.070018144  2.3541199 0.03012634

$`Oil Price`
                Estimate  Std. Error    t value  Pr(>|t|)
(Intercept) -0.001424249 0.004112478 -0.3463238 0.7331147
`Oil Price`  0.046411939 0.030404220  1.5264966 0.1442663

$`US - Canada Inflation`
                            Estimate  Std. Error    t value    Pr(>|t|)
(Intercept)             0.0001923356 0.003176245 0.06055441 0.952381362
`US - Canada Inflation` 0.0393945114 0.011325922 3.47826091 0.002683133
```

---

Note that if you are only interested in  the coefficients ie prediction, and nothing to do with hypothesis testing, you could simply run one linear regression:

```
a <- lm(`Canada Price`~ind/values+0, cbind(df1[1], stack(df1, -1)))
as.matrix(coef(a))
                                         [,1]
indGlobal Price                 -0.0015150839
indCanada 2Y Bond Price          0.0017360725
indUS - Canada Inflation         0.0001923356
indOil Price                    -0.0014242490
indGlobal Price:values           0.1648311056
indCanada 2Y Bond Price:values  -0.0257894550
indUS - Canada Inflation:values  0.0393945114
indOil Price:values              0.0464119390
```

ie where you see `:value` that is the slope and the other is the intercept. eg

intercept and slope for `Global Price` are `-0.0015150839` and `0.1648311056` respectively. Compare results to the lapply version